# "itemSwipeProgressEnded" always returns '0' on android

Tags: telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

When using the "itemSwipeProgressEnded" event on ListView element the 'x', and 'y' data are always 0 regardless of when the user ends the swipe action. Does anyone know a work around for this issue? I have submitted an issue on their github with no response so far.

Here the a playground of the described issue:

**https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=OiVkmk**

Thank you for your help

**For anyone else who has this problem before its fixed I posted a solution on github.**

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1340

Comment: Since you specified Android, it works on iOS as expected?

Comment: Yes on IOS it works.

Comment: Looks like a bug, you might want to report it on https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues

Comment: I made an issue awhile ago, I found a solution by modifying the npm package.